# How much W shape effects on the cross correlation of points in R

Tags: r, graph, spatstat

[image]

I am analyzing cross-correlation between these two-point data sets (all the analyses have been performed in R: by using `Kcross`, `Lcross` functions).

In the first trial, I was using an irregular observation window (W) considering the coast and regional boundary (the grey area in the picture). And I obtained:

[image]

In the second case I used the regular observation window (W): a rectangle with the limits of the datasets, and I obtained:

[image]

My question is: How come that I obtained **opposite results** in the first case we have only repulsion, between 0 and 2000m distance there is a correlation but with an intensity lover than confidential level, and in the second case the correlation between two data points is present on all distances.
The only thing that I changed is was a window everything else was the same...

Comment: First, you should not use an arbitrary window for evaluating a spatial process. The statistic(s) are assuming a CSR Poisson process as the null and this is derived based on the window used. An extent is not a correct representation of the CSR. Second, we really need to see code here. How are you getting the Besag-L from the K statistic? We cannot tell if the inverse if a quirk of the data and extent or if it is a mistake in your code. Have you looked at the non-transformed cross-K results? How are you implementing the randomization?

Comment: The code that I used is:
`# r vector
g <- seq(0,20000, by=25)
L.csr1 <- envelope(alldatac, Lcross, nsim=99, nrank=1, i="0",j="1", r=g)
  
plot(L.csr1,. - r ~ r,xlim=c(0, 12000), shade=NULL, col=c(1,2,3,3),legend=FALSE, xlab="Distance (r)", ylab="L Crowdsourced images vs not affected buildings", main="L cross function")`
In case of the non-transformed cross-K results I get the results wich are in line with the previously presented.